# Comparison of dataframe columns without many for loops and if statements

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm quite new to R.

I want to  compare three dataframes to see if they contain the same information within one of the columns.

The data look like this (only longer):

```
df_1
id comment coord.x  coord.y
1    <NA>  64.492 1186.803
2    <NA>  64.418 1185.560
3    <NA>  64.418 1183.001
4    <NA>  64.492 1180.953
5    <NA>  64.492 1179.345
6    <NA>  64.418 1177.517
7    <NA>  64.345 1175.396

df_2
id comment coord.x coord.y
1    <NA>   64.34 1186.73
2    <NA>   64.39 1185.42
3    <NA>   64.25 1183.04
4      #c   64.39 1181.80
5      #c   64.48 1175.26
6    <NA>   64.43 1173.41
7    <NA>   64.48 1170.12

df3
id comment coord.x  coord.y
1    <NA>  64.600 1186.769
2    <NA>  64.513 1185.377
3    <NA>  64.513 1182.984
4    <NA>  64.559 1180.722
5    <NA>  64.603 1179.286
6    <NA>  64.429 1177.502
7      #c  64.429 1174.905
```

I want to find how many truly unique values there are in coord.y, and see if the values are repeated in the three dataframes. I will consider any values that agree within 0.3 to be 'the same', ie. not unique. Then I would like to create a table of these unique coord.y values and another column which would indicate which dataframes contain this value. So 111 could indicate it is present in all three dataframes while 010 could indicate it is just present in df_2. An extra complication is that I also need to exclude any rows which contain #c from the search.

So the result for this example would be a matrix which looks like this:

```
result
1186.803    111
1185.560    111
1183.001    111 
1180.953    101
1179.345    101
1177.517    101
1175.396    100
1173.41     010
1170.12     010
```

In the end it is not so important which value is saved as the unique value. If the same value (within the 0.3 range) is found in mutliple dataframes, I may end up averaging it, but for now it is not important.

I started constructing a for loop with several if statements to do this, but it was getting rather complicated. There is probably an easier way in R to program this with functions to get a similar result.

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: If you have 3 coordinates such as 1.0, 1.2, and 1.4, which of these are the same and which are unique?

Comment: Are you only comparing `coord.y`? Do you also want `coord.x` compared independently?

Comment: Good point. I am hoping I don't have that situation in this dataset. But for the sake of coding I would say those would not considered unique, but rather the same.

Comment: Not interested in coord.x, only coord.y

Comment: ...so if you have 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, .... you want that all counted as one unique value? (e.g., `df1` has 1.0, `df2` has 1.2, `df3` has 1.4, `df1` has 1.6, ...)